# Function for Pivot Table If cell is empty or Date is After Today

Tags: filter, pivot

I am trying to filter a pivot table to track vacancies for my job, in order to do this I need to filter by both blanks and future dates(after today) in the same column. The default options are only one or the other. Is someone able to tell me how combine both "Cell is Empty" and "Date is After Today" into one filter/ value for filtering. Photos of what I am talking about. Thanks!

[Cell is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf848.png)

[After Tomorrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8j8l.png)

I have been filtering the report twice but I really just want it to filter and be done with it because every week I have been trying to remember to correct the information.